# mysql query to find number of people from birth to 3 month of age

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu

I need to find all children from my data base who died between birth to 3 months of age within the last one year, in this regard I tried to

```
Select * 
from deathstable 
where dateofbirth between (curdate() - 274), (curdate() - 183)
```

my deathstable contains name, dateoffdeath and cause.

but there seems to be some error in this. Please le me know if there is any better way of doing this.

Comment: I don't see where dateofdeath is used in your query.

Comment: deathstable has the dateofdeath inside it

Comment: sure, but you don't mention it in the query. But to die before 3 months of age, your dateofdeath must be closer to your dateofbirth than 3 months, right? How is curdate relevant at all?

Comment: @choroba I have edited my question to make it clearer. I need deaths of all toddlers less than 3 months within the past year that is why I am using curdate()

Comment: _but there seems to be some error in this_ Yes, a SQL Syntax error. Read the Manual.... **any** SQL manual and correct the syntax error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking it might be better to actually subtract dateofbirth from dateofdisposal so that age always remains 3 months. I have not edited the previous answer incase that one suits you better.
something like:

> (datediff (dateofdeath, dateofbirth) < 91))